# How to properly intertwine html and php. I'm new to this

Tags: php, html

In the below lines of code, I have php intertwined with html. For some reason, after the echo <<<_END none of that code is being recognized. How can I fix this? I'm somewhat new to this

```
  <th>Member Password</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="membertable">
                <?php
                    $query="SELECT * FROM member";
                    $result=$conn->query($query);
                    if(!$result) die ($conn->error);

                    $rows=$result->num_rows;
                    for($j=0; $j<$rows; $j++) {
                        $result->data_seek($j);
                        $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
                        echo <<<_END
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="UseCase6-Modify-Existing-Member?id=$row[0]">$row[0]</a></td>
                                <td>$row[1]</td>
                                <td>$row[2]</td>
                                <td>$row[3]</td>
                                <td>$row[4]</td>
                                <td>$row[5]</td>
                                <td>$row[6]</td>
                                <td>$row[7]</td>
                                <td>$row[8]</td>
                                <td>$row[9]</td>
                                <td>$row[10]</td>
                            </tr>
                        _END;
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#memberinput").on("keyup", function () {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#membertable tr").filter(function () {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you don't set string for echo. Try replace your string:

```
echo <<<_END
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="UseCase6-Modify-Existing-Member?id=$row[0]">$row[0]</a></td>
                                <td>$row[1]</td>
                                <td>$row[2]</td>
                                <td>$row[3]</td>
                                <td>$row[4]</td>
                                <td>$row[5]</td>
                                <td>$row[6]</td>
                                <td>$row[7]</td>
                                <td>$row[8]</td>
                                <td>$row[9]</td>
                                <td>$row[10]</td>
                            </tr>
                        _END;
```

with:

```
echo "
    <tr>
        <td><a href='UseCase6-Modify-Existing-Member?id=$row[0]'>$row[0]</a></td>
        <td>$row[1]</td>
        <td>$row[2]</td>
        <td>$row[3]</td>
        <td>$row[4]</td>
        <td>$row[5]</td>
        <td>$row[6]</td>
        <td>$row[7]</td>
        <td>$row[8]</td>
        <td>$row[9]</td>
        <td>$row[10]</td>
    </tr>
";
```

Comment: Hello Au- I made that change based on your suggestion, and am now getting the following parse error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'UseCase6' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\testfiles\UseCase8-Manage-Members.php on line 49. Line 49 is as follows:                                                      <td><a href="UseCase6-Modify-Existing-Member.php?id=$row[0]">$row[0]</a></td>      any thoughts?